# how to find the name of the div that corresponds to the label used in the code inspector?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to find a way to add margin-auto to a tailwinds css class, so that I can center an svg image across a container. I can add the attribute in code inspect, but I cannot find the corresponding div tag in my code.

The inspect panel shows the div as tailwinds.css.1, but I don't have a class with that name. I have tried adding margin-auto to the svg tag itself and all the surrounding div tags, as well as the Logo component in which the svg is defined. None of them work to center the image.

How can I find the name of the div tag from the inspect panel?

```
<footer className="bg-slate-50">
      <Container>
        <div className="py-16 display-block  mx-auto">
          
          <Logo className="display-block  mx-auto" />
```

[image]

Comment: _"The inspect panel shows the div as tailwinds.css.1, but I don't have a class with that name."_ - `tailwinds.css.1` is referring the the URL of that stylesheet, and the line number where the rule started ... _"shows the div as"_ is phrasing that makes little sense to begin with. Apart from that you are not actually inspecting the div there, but the svg, that panel shows what CSS rules apply to the inspected element.

Comment: _"How can I find the name of the div tag from the inspect panel?"_ - what "name", div elements don't have a "name". Are you trying to ask, what selector you could use to _target_ this div element? Well if you don't have any classes or IDs available that allow to target it directly, then find a way to target it based on its relationship to other elements. Assuming you only have one `footer` element on the page, something like `footer > div > div:first-child svg` could do. (I think you actually want to target the svg and not the parent div.)

Comment: I have tried adding mx-auto to both the svg and the Logo component and the div around Logo. None of these actually centre the svg on the screen. The screenshot I shared shows how I can add margin:auto to the css panel in the code inspect in the console, to center the svg. I can't find where to add the attribute in the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mx-auto** on the svg should do the trick

https://play.tailwindcss.com/o33Y2yn5KP

Comment: yep - I had to put it in the svg file tag. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to inspect the required component you can use the DOM methods. For example if you want to target the  `<div className="py-16 display-block  mx-auto">` , you can use  like

```
document.getElementByTagName("Container").getFirstElementChild()
```

For centering the Logo, you just to need the `mx-auto` to that component only .I have rewritten your code below.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<footer class="bg-slate-50">
  <div class="container mx-auto"> <!-- adding the container class to the this outer div -->
    <div class="py-16 display-block">
      <!-- Consider it as you LOGO component -->
      <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2 mx-auto" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
        <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
      </svg>
      <!-- LOGO compnent ends -->
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Try to implement this but remember to replace `class` with `className`.

Also you can view the code with more better preview [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/x4iRyjhTEj)

Comment: As you can see from the code snippet I shared above, there is already a Container div around logo. I also tried adding a separate div, that has the Logo component nested inside it (only). I have tried adding display block and mx-auto to each of these, and they do not resolve to center the logo. The screenshot I shared shows that I can center it from the code inspect, but i can't find where to put that attribute in the code - which is why I've asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to change **display-block** by only **block** on your logo component ?

**display-block** doesn't exist in tailwindcss

Comment: I tried adding both display-block and mx-auto, in combination and with mx-auto alone. I cannot get the logo to centre. I can do it in the code inspect by adding margin: auto where shown in the screenshot I shared.

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot, display:block is required to get the svg to center. When I hover over it in code inspect, it shows a full width margin on the right of the svg and I can't find the source of it or how to displace it.